# Best way to store websites to check in Chrome without overloading computer with tabs

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I often open many tabs from links that I want to check later.
The links are usually not something I want to use long term.
I often work on a computer that isn't high spec.
I want to continue my work as fast as possible.
I usually do not want to open the links, I just want to store it for later.

Considering the above, what would be the best way to store websites for later.
Chrome extension or existing Chrome functionality would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a related answer on another stackexchange website.
It seems to mostly answer my question.
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21822/chrome-extension-for-bookmarking-links

Answer (score 0):

I often do the same. The main other problem beside performance is that often chrome end up closed and when re-open, all opened tabs restored but reloaded. There are many ways to go for such approach though.

**Using bookmarking**. From the menu go to `Bookmarks` then `Show bookmarks bar`. Now when you opened multiple tabs, right click on one of them and select `Bookmark all tabs...`. Make new folder for these tabs and name it as you wish and put the folder on the bookmark bar. That way you can load them all by right clicking on that folder and re-open all of them (or separately if you wish) at whatever time you like.

**Pin the tabs**. Right clicking on the tab then choosing `Pin Tab` is another way to keep the tabs for later. You can select multiple tabs by holding *Ctrl + Left* single clicking on every tab you wish (You will notice that selected tabs are brighter than others).

I'm sure there are more ways. But performance wise, you might want to consider saving them as bookmarks and reload every one (or couple..etc) at a time.